# 16 year old nephew passport without legal guardian documents

Tags: paperwork

My sister took in a baby from a friend 16 years ago and the mother of that baby died. My sister was awarded temporary custody that expired in 90 days. She never legally adopted him, no one from the state ever contacted her and her husband. He has always attended school and has had all the appropriate medical care.My sister died when this boy was 7. Her husband has no legal documentation stating he is the guardian. The child’s birth certificate states the biological mother’s name, and “parts unknown” where the father’s name should be. We don’t know who the father is or any other family. He has always been with us. I have his biological mother’s death certificate.We are planning a trip to Alaska and part of it will go through Canada.I know he can apply for a passport but does anyone know what to expect with no legal paperwork for a child who has been in our family since he was born? I have no idea how the schools have dealt with this.My sister’s husband has end stage kidney disease and is awaiting transplant and will probably pass away before he turns 18.

Comment: Getting the passport is only one problem.  There will be others.  Find a lawyer who practises family law and do what needs to be done to formalize the child's guardianship.  This will solve the passport problem and the others as well.

Comment: Based on the trip to Alaska going through Canada...passport, this sounds like (but isn't 100% clear) everyone currently lives in the US. Assuming that's the case: Does your nephew have a social security number? Has your brother-in-law (and previously your sister) been including him as a dependent on tax returns? These things don't *necessarily* relate to getting a passport but may be relevant (a lawyer should know) to formalizing guardianship.

Comment: I know an attorney is the answer, phong,but brother in law has been uncooperative. 
I didn’t think about the social security and tax implications because he does and is, thanks for the tip. I know they don’t care about misc documentation, but getting supportive documentation showing his unofficial custody might help. I hate to start any legal issues with everything else going on.Thanks manassehkatz

Comment: Phoog, stupid autocorrect

Comment: Yes, we all are US citizens, I should have said that first. He still needs a passport to board the ship and to cross over into Canada and back into the US is my understanding

Comment: No problem about the autocorrect.  On the question of the lawyer, I'm thinking about what might happen for example if your brother in law passes away before your nephew's 18th birthday.  Back to the passport, and looking at the requirements for a US passport for a 16- or 17-year-old, it seems that formal proof of the guardianship would be needed, though I haven't looked closely for loopholes.  As you seem to be taking a cruise, you might ask the cruise line if there are exceptions for children of his age, but I believe you're right that he'll need a passport.